# Why do some market makers have many Market Participant Identifiers (MPIDs)?

Tags: united-states, financial-literacy, market-making

I noticed that some (most?) market making firms have many Market Participant Identifiers (MPIDs). For example, from the list of NASDAQ market participants<sup>1</sup>:

- "Jane Street Capital, LLC" has the following MPIDs: JANE, JNST, JSAP, JSCA, JSCT, JSJX, JSML.
- "Virtu Americas LLC" has the following MPIDs: ALTX, DTTX, GFLO, ITGF, ITGG, ITGI, ITGP, KCGB, KCGC, KCGM, NITC, NITE, VALD, VALR, VALX, VIRT, VNMS, VRTU.

I observe the same pattern with other firms such as Cantor Fitzgerald & Co., GTS Securities LLC, Citadel Securities LLC, etc.

I'm aware that some of the MPIDs for Virtu can be attributed to acquisitions of other market making firms (e.g. KCG Holdings, Inc., Investment Technology Group, Inc., etc.), but what about the rest of its MPIDs? If not mistaken, Jane Street has not made any acquisitions of market making firms. Why does it have so many MPIDs?

---

<sup>1</sup> ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/mpidlist.txt

Comment: https://www.nasdaqtrader.com/dynamic/Symdir/mpidlist.txt seems to be the same list but as a webpage rather than FTP link. Of the many "multi-MPID" examples in the list, many have differing entries in the **MP Type** field (e.g. "P" or "M"). Also note many MPIDs aren't (directly) owned by the same entity: JSAP is JANE STREET CAPITAL, LLC, JSEP is JANE STREET EXECUTION SERVICES, LLC. My guess would be it's so if something bad happens to one part, it won't necessarily affect another part.

Comment: I hadn't noticed you'd listed MPIDs that exclusively, sorry. Also, just in case you thought so, I wasn't meaning to SHOUT OUT the difference in the LLC names, that's just how the two I picked were capitalised.

Comment: @TripeHound "Also note many MPIDs aren't (directly) owned by the same entity..." I am well aware of this. Notice how the list of MPIDs in my question only includes those of "Jane Street Capital, LLC" (exact case-insensitive match). I am not asking about "JANE STREET EXECUTION SERVICES, LLC" or "JANE STREET OPTIONS, LLC". I am simply asking why "Jane Street Capital, LLC" has multiple MPIDs.